# How do you code a program that outputs a number triangle given a height, but only using while loops (lists, range, for loops are not allowed)

Tags: python

Sample Input:

```
  5
  2
  3
```

Sample Output:

```
  1
  1 2 
  1 2 3
  1 2 3 4 
  1 2 3 4 5

  1
  1 2 

  1 
  1 2 
  1 2 3
```

The only ways I have seen how to do it is by using range, lists, and for loops. I am required to only use while loops to make the number triangle. I can only use string concatenation to build the string. So I can't code it like this:

```
    outer = 1
    while outer <=6:
        inner = 1
        while inner <= outer:
            print(inner, end=" ")
            inner = inner + 1
        print(" ")
        outer = outer + 1
```

Comment: Do you have any piece of code that we can iterate on?

Comment: This is just asking for homework to be done by us...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid loops, lists and ranges, you can use recursion.

For example:

```
# assemble a line of numbers
def numberLine(N):
    return "1" if N==1 else numberLine(N-1) + " " + str(N)

# assemble lines 
def numberTriangle(N):
    return "1" if N==1 else numberTriangle(N-1) + "\n" + numberLine(N)
```

output:

```
print(numberTriangle(5))
                         
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

If you are allowed while loops (aka poor man's for loop), an iterative approach may be easier to grasp:

```
def printNumberTriangle(N):
    n = 1
    s = "1"
    while n <= N:
        print(s)
        n = n + 1
        s = s + " " + str(n)
```

output:

```
printNumberTriangle(5)
                         
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: OP claims that you cannot print individual numbers, but have to concatenate them into a string.

Comment: Fixed it (using two separate functions)

Comment: Very epic. Upvoting c: